# MySQL JOIN overrides original table values

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to implement a JOIN with two tables, but have stumbled upon a little problem.
I've got the following data structure:

**Original table** 
ID - Name - Value
1  - John - Clerk
2  - Jack - Driver

**Join table** 
ID - Name
1  - John
2  - Jack
3  - Matt

I need to join my tables so that the result will be the following:

**Result**
ID - Name - Value
1  - John - Clerk
2  - Jack - Driver
3  - Matt - null

So, I wrote the following statement `SELECT * FROM original_table LEFT JOIN join_table ON  original_table.ID GROUP BY join_table.ID`

And it returns me the following result:

**Result**
ID - Name - Value
1  - John - Clerk
2  - Jack - Clerk
3  - Matt - Clerk

What should I fix in order to value column be ignored during the join?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you want to select from the table you've called "join table" and left join onto the original table. Or maybe you want to inner join. You haven't given a clear enough example to know for sure. You definitely don't want to select from that first table and left join from the second like you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *swap* the table names
- *remove* the group by clause.

Try the following,

```
SELECT  a.id, a.name, b.value
FROM    join_table a 
        LEFT JOIN original b
            on a.id = b.id
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7da3d/1)

Comment: Why would you make the original table "b"? That's confusing

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

SELECT * FROM join_table LEFT JOIN original_table ON original_table.ID = join_table.id;